# In Java, why does `Integer.parseInt("10000000000000000000000000000000"), 2)` throw a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, numberformatexception, parseint

I'm using OpenJDK17 and am perplexed as to why `Integer.parseInt("10000000000000000000000000000000", 2)` would throw a `NumberFormatException` as it is the binary representation of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (or `-2147483648` in decimal).

Is this expected or some known edge-case/quirk?

I attempted to provide the binary representation of Java's `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.parseInt` in order to receive back `-2147483648` but inside experience a `NumberFormatException`.

Note: I'm not particularly trying to achieve anything just fiddling around on the JVM and came across this.

Comment: The posted code has syntax errors.

Comment: This will produce the value you want: `Integer.parseInt("-10000000000000000000000000000000", 2)`.

Comment: @ScottHunter interesting thank you - still seems incorrect that without the negative an exception would be thrown.

Comment: I think it is treating the digits as an unsigned value.

Comment: You can store `-2147483648` in an int, but only `+2147483647`, which is `1111111111111111111111111111111`. So there's actually no surprise there.

Comment: `ParseInt` may use a prefix `+` or `-` sign to indicate whether the number is positive or negative.  That the value of the radix argument is `2` does *not* create an exception to allow the first digit to specify the sign. So, the first argument overflows an `int`.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I think that's the answer - regardless of it being binary (radix 2), it's still looking for the pos/neg prefix which would explain the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Integer.parseInt()` method with the radix of `2` is not used to convert a bit representation of a two's complement integer value to an `int` value. Instead it "just" parsed the string as a signed integer with the given radix. What that means is that "10000000000000000000000000000000" in binary is 2147483648 in decimal. Such a big value cannot be saved as `int` in java because the maximum `int` value in java is 2147483647 (or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`). That's why you get a `NumberFormatException`. The result will not be a negative value like `Integer.MIN_VALUE` what you expected. The result will only be negative when the first character in the string is a `-` character as mentioned in the [javadoc of `Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-):

> [...] except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value [...]

Comment: Great explanation - thank you!

Comment: Note that you can still get the notion of 'I have in bit representation some number, turn that into an int' is possible: `int x = 0b10000000000000000000000000000000;` (yes, that's rare but valid java, `0b` was introduced in Java 1.7, a very long time ago).

Comment: Of course, if you have that value in a string containing only 1s and 0s, it's not that simple. Easiest way forward is to just parse it as a long and go from there.

Comment: @rzwitserloot you could use [`Integer.parseUnsignedInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt(java.lang.String,int)): _Parses the string argument as an unsigned integer in the radix specified by the second argument. An unsigned integer maps the values usually associated with negative numbers to positive numbers larger than MAX_VALUE._